# ¿Tiene la palabra "frustrar" connotaciones sexuales?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, coloquialismos

Otros (incluyendo maestros) me han dicho no usar la palabra "frustrar", porque dicen que tiene una connotación sexual - y por esto la definición es distinta de la "to frustrate" en inglés. ¿Es esta su experiencia? ¿Hay otras frases que se puedan usar en vez de "esto me frustra" o "estoy frustrado" cuando la situación es inocente? ¿Hay usos distintos en España y América?

Comment: Soy español y nunca diría que la palabra "frustrar" tenga connotaciones sexuales, ni la más mínima...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes native speakers bend over backwards to protect new Spanish speakers from committing faux pas.  My personal opinion about "frustrar" and "frustrado/frustrada" is that it depends a great deal on the context -- and perhaps the country.  My answer is based on my experience living in Mexico, an extremely machista society, where sexual innuendo is rampant, and young foreigners, especially women, are particularly vulnerable.  In many parts of the country, young foreign women sometimes feel like wearing ear protectors, just walking down the street.  One could make a whole socio-political analysis of the causes, probably starting with *Para Leer a Pato Donald*, but I would like to get to OP's question now.

An unadorned (i.e. contextless) comment such as

> ¡Me siento frustrado/frustrada!

could be misinterpreted, I suppose.  It is certainly true that these two words are used MUCH less often in Spanish than in English.  So it wouldn't be a bad idea to learn some alternatives, since learning a new language always involves lots of frustration, and it's natural that you would want to talk about that as you are practicing and communicating with people.  So here are some ideas:

> Esto es difícil
>
> Esto es tan difícil
>
> No me va bien
>
> No me va bien con ... (la gramática, este tema, los verbos, entender a la gente, explicar mi idea, etc.)
>
> Tuvimos un malentendido
>
> Me va mal con ... (el subjuntivo, etc.)
>
> Se me dificulta ... (entender a la gente, expresar mis ideas, etc.)

The other thing you can do is cultivate patience with yourself.  If you can do this, you will have less of a need to express frustration, because you'll be experiencing frustration less often and with less intensity.  When learning a language and getting acculturated, there will be many, many misunderstandings.  Most you can just let go with the tide.  For the biggies, here's a pattern that can help:

> De haber entendido ..., hubiera / no hubiera ...

Here's an example from my earliest steps in communicating in Spanish:

> De haber entendido que no me iban a pagar la primera quincena, no hubiera gastado todo el dinero en efectivo que traje. | *If I had understood that my first salary payment would be delayed, I would not have spent all the cash I brought with me for the transition.*

(This was from a long time ago, before the ubiquitous use of credit cards.  It was indeed a biggie.)

---

Perdón, acabo de repasar la pregunta y me dí cuenta que escribiste tu pregunta en español.  (¡Te quedó muy bien!  Solo una cosita cambiaría: *me han dicho no usar la palabra "frustrar"* quedaría mejor así: *me han dicho que no debo usar la palabra "frustrar"*.)

Avísame, por favor, si quieres que ponga mi respuesta en español.

Comment: No me importa en cual lengua me escribe. Gracias.

Comment: Comprueba las otras respuestas. Pensar que "me siento frustrado" pueda ser malinterpretado no tiene base alguna, todos coincidimos.

Comment: @FGSUZ - Me pregunto por qué tanta gente le ha dado el consejo a OP a no usar esta expresión.

Comment: No entiendo el voto negativo para esta respuesta.

Answer (score 3):

Tus profesores y otros están total y absolutamente errados.

La palabra *frustrar*, que ni siquiera posee tal connotación sexual en la RAE, entrega dicha definición.
Considerando lo anterior, puedes usarla con su respectiva definición.

Answer (score 2):

Como padre de dos niños, uso constantemente el verbo *frustrar* sin que tenga absolutamente ninguna connotación sexual. Si miramos la definición, leemos lo siguiente:

> **[frustrar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IXNBGPl)**
>
> ```
> Del lat. frustrāre.
> ```
>
> 1. tr. Privar a alguien de lo que esperaba.
> 2. tr. Dejar sin efecto, malograr un intento. U. t. c. prnl.
> 3. tr. Der. Dejar sin efecto un propósito contra la intención de quien procura realizarlo. *Frustrar un delito.* U. t. c. prnl.

Ninguna de las tres acepciones mostradas tiene implicaciones sexuales. Acerca de lo que te comentaba de los niños, yo la uso mucho en su primera acepción. Por ejemplo, cuando el niño me pide que le deje la tablet para ver YouTube Kids y yo le digo que no hay tiempo que tenemos que irnos al cole, el niño se frustra (le privo de algo que esperaba).

Sí que es cierto que esta palabra se puede usar en infinidad de contextos. Por ejemplo, si tu pareja te dice que esta noche no, que le duele la cabeza, pues te puedes sentir frustrado (te han privado de algo que esperabas), y en este caso sí es por algo sexual, pero esa connotación la da el contexto, no la palabra en sí.

Así pues, el uso del verbo *frustrar* por sí solo ("estoy frustrado") puede hacer que la gente indague en el origen de tu frustración en busca del contexto perdido. Así que en principio puedes usarla con seguridad.

Por último, la palabra *frustrar* no aparece en el *Diccionario de americanismos*, por lo que entiendo que no tiene otro tipo de connotaciones en Hispanoamérica, y su definición de la RAE aplica a todo el mundo hispanohablante.